# Extract text from class using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of dashboard pages rendered and view elements coded for one page that looks like:

```
<td class="secondaryTabSelected" title="Pace">
        <span tabindex="0">Pace</span>
</td>
```

---

I want to extract the name called "Pace" from above using `Javascript`, after the user has clicked on a specific tab title called "Pace".  How can I achieve this?

**I have tried:**

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('secondaryTabSelected')[0];
var b = a.getElementsByClassName("child")[0].innerHTML;
alert(b);     //assume b is my extracted text
```

Comment: where is the class "child" ?  `a.textContent`

Comment: @epascarello - sorry there was no class ... was just trying different syntax... but the first solution works what I was trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is often a better function to use when trying to query the DOM for elements. It essentially allows you to use CSS selector syntax to perform more complicated queries (much like jQuery) and has support down to IE8.

In your case:

```
var spanElement = document.querySelectorAll(".secondaryTabSelected span")[0];

alert(spanElement.innerText);
```

Should perform what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thats was worked . Now I have different challenge to refer to extract text "Demand:Stay Date 90 Day Buildup" from below but not  sure how can I use previous syntax you gave :                                                    <td class="BreadCrumbItemTd" id="bcitem1"><span id="breadCrumbSpan1" class="BreadCrumbCurrentItem">Demand360: Stay Date 90 Day Buildup</span></td>

Comment: You just need to change the class selector to `.BreadCrumbItemTd` instead of `.secondaryTabSelected` 

Comment: I was doing "breadCrumbSpan1" instead of "BreadCrumbItemTd" . But since it didn't help I did below and seems working : var spanElement = document.querySelectorAll("span.BreadCrumbCurrentItem");
alert( spanElement[0].innerText) ;

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. td need to be nested in  in  node, otherwise the browser will remove the tag.
2. you haven't put child as a class in html

You can either remove the first line and add class direclty in your target node or use [childNodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) instead

```js
 var a = document.getElementsByClassName('secondaryTabSelected')[0];

 console.log(a); 

 var b = a.childNodes[1].innerHTML

 console.log(b);
```

```html
<div class="secondaryTabSelected" title="Pace">
        <span tabindex="0">Pace</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That works too .  Now I have different challenge to extract text "Demand:Stay Date 90 Day Buildup" from below but not sure how can I use previous syntax you gave : <td class="BreadCrumbItemTd" id="bcitem1"><span id="breadCrumbSpan1" class="BreadCrumbCurrentItem">Demand360: Stay Date 90 Day Buildup</span></td> –

Comment: @pauldx Please consider use className on dom object. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp